# Вылетает из пользовотеля при попытке в него войти

Tags: windows-10

После очередного обновления *Windows 10* (**1709**), заходит во всех пользователей кроме одного (их всего 2), в администратора что даже очень странно, заходит. пользователь в которого не получается зайти имеет следующие полномочия и параметры

```
Полномочия: Обычный Пользователь,
Привязан к учетной записи Microsoft: Нет,
Тип аутентификации: Не имеется,
Родительский Контроль: Не имеется
```

Что-же могло стать причиной данного происшествия, какие дополнительные параметры пользователя предоставить?

Comment: Вход по паролю или ПИН-коду?

Comment: Без пароля и пин